# Making multiple requests to Spotify add to queue endpoint

Tags: node.js, api, express, request, spotify

I’m developing an application using Express and I need to call the Spotify endpoint to [add to a user’s queue](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/add-to-queue/) multiple times with different parameters, basically in a for loop. All requests return a 2xx status code, but not all of the tracks were actually added to my queue. It could be that only one was added, or multiple, but never all. I’m not really sure how to debug this because the call is returning a 2xx response code every time, so I’m wondering if perhaps there’s a general rule of thumb for making multiple calls to an API.

Here is where I call addToQueue in a loop:

```
let finishedRequests = 0
            requests.forEach(async r => {
                addToQueue(r.songId, accessToken, async () => {
                    try {
                        await RequestModel.findByIdAndUpdate(r._id, { $set: { serviced: true, accepted }})
                        return {
                            status: 200
                        }
                    } catch(err) {
                        return {
                            status: 500,
                            message: JSON.stringify(err)
                        }
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                       
                        
                        if (response.status === 500) {
                            
                            return res.status(500).json({ err: err.message })
                        }
                        finishedRequests++
                      
                         if (finishedRequests === requests.length) {
                            return res.status(200).send()
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                       
                        return res.status(err.status).json({ err: err.message})
                    })
```

And here is the addToQueue function:

```
const addToQueue = (songId, accessToken, successCallback) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=spotify:track:${songId}`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` 
            },
            json: true
        }
        requestModule.post(options, async (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
                
                resolve(successCallback())
            } else {
                if (error) {
                    reject({
                        status: 500,
                        mesage: JSON.stringify(error)
                    })
                } else {
                    if (response.statusCode === 404) {
                        reject({
                            status: 404,
                            message: 'no queue'
                        })
                    }
                    reject({
                        status: response.statusCode,
                        message: 'spotify error'
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
    
}
```

Any help in making sure that all tracks are added to the queue is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem but solved it by making sure all requests are executed one after the other. You should try using a recursive function instead of the `forEach`. Once a request returns a positive status you would rerun the same function but only with the remaining songs as the parameter.

This way the requests will be added to the queue in the correct order and you won't add a bulk of songs in the same second. This also brings the benefit that you can be pretty sure that the songs will be in the right order when arriving in the Spotify queue.

I hope I could help!